# How Stack Overflow "similar questions" algorithm works

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, search

I asked a question with the title [List out of List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382679/list-out-of-list-c-sharp).

The box "Questions that may already have your answer" didn't show me if the question had already been asked.

The question I have been told is a duplicate has the title [C# Select elements in list as List of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885748/c-sharp-select-elements-in-list-as-list-of-string)

Now both titles have familiar keywords, like "list" and "C#."

Also, these words are quite close to each other, so why didn't the Stack Overflow search algorithm pick it up?

[image: Title search results]

Comment: Well, one problem is probably that the title *List out of List C#* is not descriptive. I would have absolutely no clue what the question was about until I read it. Stack Overflow can pick out pretty much only *List* from the title. C# is already a tag, so it doesn't need that in the title.

Comment: Exactly. Look at the keywords of the other question compared to yours: *Select elements*, *list*, *list of string* compared to *list*.

Comment: No, but I doubt you do either. I'm just trying to put it into perspective. I can't imagine a human matching those two up by their titles alone. If you don't agree with me, that's fine, but there's no need to be treating me like an idiot when I'm trying to help...

Comment: "No, but I doubt you do either." that's why i asked this question :S

Comment: Yes, it uses keywords to find potential matches. But if it only has "list" and "C#" to work with, you can't expect it to do a particularly good job.