# What is the algorithm/metric used to determine question similarity?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, similar-questions

When one asks a question on stackoverflow, a list of already asked questions (ranked in order of most similar to least similar?) are displayed to the user.

How is this similarity determined?  Does it use simple pattern recognition (e.g. n-grams)?  Does it incorporate semantic information present in the questions themselves (e.g. leveraging information from WordNet or some other natural language semantic database of English?)?  Does it make use of natural language parsers to interpret the content of the question?

Of course I didn't even ask how stackoverflow performs the search.

In trying to find if this question has been asked before, these two questions were at the top of the list.  Conspicuously, they are *still* **unanswered**.

(1) [How Stack Overflow "similar questions" algorithm works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269171/how-stack-overflow-similar-questions-algorithm-works)

This question is more about a specific case that the algorithm apparently didn't pick up on, though the user makes it the title of the question.  It has no answer as of August 28, 2014.

(2) ["Similar Questions" search should take the tags into account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269706/similar-questions-search-should-take-the-tags-into-account)

This question asks about the internals of the algorithm and what role (if any) tags play in determining similar questions to one being generated in real time by the user.  It seems that tags do not play a huge role, as I haven't even put tags on this question yet been offered very accurate suggestions of similar questions.

Furthermore, the question was a yes or no: **are tags incorporated in the similarity metric / algorithm for questions? (and if so what is their 'weight')?**  But again there is no answer yet.

This paper also seems to suggest tags aren't too important in the algorithm / metric, as it seems they can be predicted reasonably well just from the content of the question being asked.

(3) http://iccm-conference.org/2013-proceedings/papers/0077/paper0077.pdf

Stackoverflow also does some tag prediction as well.

Ideally the answer to my question would be a high level description of the metric followed by a link to the source code.

(Also another funny thing is that the tag similar-questions is just recently made, this is the second time it's ever been used according to the tag history, the first time was in question (1)).

Comment: I don't suppose you had any luck with uncovering this mystery during the last year?

Comment: At the time I wrote it I was a naive student, and Stackoverflow obviously isn't just about to open source its algorithms.  A good approximation would be to use Stackoverflow as training data for your own question similarity ranker.

Comment: Thanks, did you manage to approximate it? Can you share anything? Which algorithm would you recommend? Would it be machine learning or similarity scoring?