# What is the recommendation system used for tags and similar questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, answer-similar-questions

I am working in data science and pretty sure I am proposing the obvious, but do you use a recommender engine for the tags that does this not only from the raw tokens of the text but based on higher level features? The same question goes for the recommender system for similar questions. Is there any page that describes the systems that are implemented? I would be very curious to know what is under the hood of one of my most used pages on the net :)

Comment: The canonical "under the hood" post is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369), but that doesn't really answer this specific question. [This question about "similar question" recommendations is relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270049), also. Haven't seen anything yet about how tag prediction is done. [This list of academic papers related to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data/134496#134496) might also be interesting to you.

Comment: This might give you some idea: https://twitter.com/drob/status/789485322895822849 It also includes a score on each tag that you might be interested in. Maybe you can also ask him directly on twitter or send the link?