# "Similar questions" recommendation algorithm: is it open-source?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

When we write a new question title (`/ask`), a list of already-existing  similar questions is suggested in a list under the title.

This algorithm works surprisingly well. Is it open-source? If not, is there an article giving details about it?

If we're really lucky, maybe someone has a Python code that would demonstrate it (provided we have a local copy of the SO dump)?

Comment: Not sure if you are asking for the internals or if you are asking *"How can I implement a Similar Question Lookup using python"*. If the latter, you should ask this on the main page (Not sure if this is a little bit to broad)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Just for learning purposes, I'd love to see how such an algorithm works (not only the general hand-waved ideas, but also an implementation), because I enjoy reading about great algorithms in action.

Comment: SO can never be open source. There's so many copy cat sites just copy/pasting SO contents to generate traffic for themselves. Imagine if they could copy the whole site as well.

Comment: @Lundin false. The copy cat sites are often styled quite differently to avoid being accused or direct copying. Also you couldn't recreate the community on each and every site.

Comment: @Lundin And copy cat sites can't copy Jon Skeet, he copies himself

Answer (score 16):

It seems highly unlikely that the algorithm is open source.

The algorithm [is not one of Stack Exchange's GitHub repos](https://github.com/StackExchange). Questions asking about the nature of the algorithm have not been answered:

1. [What is the algorithm/metric used to determine question similarity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270049/what-is-the-algorithm-metric-used-to-determine-question-similarity)
2. [How Stack Overflow "similar questions" algorithm works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269171/how-stack-overflow-similar-questions-algorithm-works)

The [results of the algorithm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348825/458741) are used to alert potential question askers that their question might be of low quality.

Comment: Are there attempts from users to code such an algorithm (for learning purposes) from a SO dump? That would be super interesting.

Comment: You might be better off looking through the list of [academic papers that use Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134495/179419) @Basj.

Comment: I am not sure I get the last sentence's purpose. Is it just a free added info, or does it really try to explain the first sentence as a dooming argument? If the latter, I wonder what are the odds that someone would go reading the source code of this algo simply to avoid this warning message triggers, and if they did, wouldn't they also simply post a better quality question? ("*Mission f*** accomplished*")

Comment: @Ben  Thank god it's not open source. All we need is more and more people trying to abuse it.

Comment: @Skipper so is it basically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity ?

Comment: It's just freely added info @kaiido. Some uses of the algorithm are freely open, not the thing itself.

Comment: @Skipper Who is going to abuse it? Users who can't even understand their own code and post bad questions? Or who do you expect to make that much effort to understand the algorithm, just to post bad question?